# Python: Create associative array in a loop

Tags: python, associative-array

I want to create an associative array with values read from a file. My code looks something like this, but its giving me an error saying i can't the indicies must be ints.

Thanks =]

```
for line in open(file):
  x=prog.match(line)
  myarray[x.group(1)]=[x.group(2)]
```

Comment: Since your code is incomplete, we have to guess.  Please include **all** the relevant code.  `myarray`, for example, must be initialized somewhere or you'd get a NameError.  Please include **all** the relevant code.

Answer (score 17):

```
myarray = {} # Declares myarray as a dict
for line in open(file, 'r'):
    x = prog.match(line)
    myarray[x.group(1)] = [x.group(2)] # Adds a key-value pair to the dict
```

Answer (score 5):

Associative arrays in Python are called mappings. The most common type is the [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Thanks ignacio, but how would i add it via loop if i dont know all the values ahead of time.

Comment: Start with an empty dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Because array indices should be an integer

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a['r'] = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>> a[1] = 4
>>> a
[1, 4, 3]
```

x.group(1) should be an integer or

**if you are using map define the map first**

```
myarray = {}
for line in open(file):
  x=prog.match(line)
  myarray[x.group(1)]=[x.group(2)]
```

Comment: but i want an associative array, aka hash table, or mapping